# how to send array of bytes with using the websocket in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying using this code but it shows me this error
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'ws://192.168.4.1/ws' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

```
var  sock = await Socket.connect('ws://192.168.4.1/ws', 80);
var  socket = WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket(sock, serverSide: false);
  socket.listen((message){

});

  var list = utf8.encode("DATA");
  var data = list is Uint8List ? list : Uint8List.fromList(list);


  socket.addUtf8Text(data);
```